# How do I append multiple taxonomies to the URL?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, taxonomy, customization

## Multiple taxonomies in URL

#### How does one append multiple taxonomies to the URL having the following:

> - Post Type: **products**
> - Taxonomy: **product_type**
> - Taxonomy: **product_brand**

#### Adding new product and selecting type and brand for this product:

When adding a new ***product***, there are two taxonomy boxes (product_type and product_brand). Let's call this new post ***Test Product 1***. The first thing we want to do is tick what type of product I'm dealing with, let's say ***cell-phones***. Next, I want to tick what brand the product belongs to, let's say ***samsung.***

Now "***Test Product 1***" is associated with the type ***"cell-phones"*** and the brand ***"samsung"***.

**The desired end result is:**

> **/products** 
>   » View all custom posts
>
> **/products/cell-phones** 
>   » View all custom posts with the taxonomy cell-phones
>
> **/product/cell-phones/samsung/** 
>   » View all custom posts where the taxonomy is cell-phones **AND** samsung
>
> **/products/cell-phones/samsung/test-product-1** 
>   » View the product (single custom post)

#### The question

How would one make this possible? My initial thought was using one taxonomy, having ***"cell-phones"*** as the parent term of ***"samsung"***. Actually appending the taxonomy and its terms was not so tough. But it led to a lot of other issues, some well known, some not so much. Anyway it doesn't work like that as it gives 404 issues and WP won't allow certain things. 

[WP.org » taxonomy-archive-template](http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/taxonomy-archive-template/page/2)

This lead me to having rethought the structure, having to leave taxonomies and its terms and I thought; why not create a 2nd taxonomy, and associate the post type with it and append that to the url?

Good question indeed, but how?

Comment: can you check this link i have issue with same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351477/combine-multiple-custom-user-taxonomy-in-single-url?noredirect=1#comment56758571_34351477

Answer (score 9):

This is certainly possible by utilizing some rewrite rules of your own to some extent. The [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) API exposes functions that allow you to add rewrite rules (or 'maps') to convert a request to a query.

There are prerequisites to writing good rewrite rules, and the most important one is basic regular expression comprehension. The WordPress Rewrite engine uses regular expressions to translate parts of a URL to queries to get posts with.

[This](http://www.tipsntutorials.com/tutorials/PHP/50) is a short and good tutorial on PHP PCRE (Perl compatible regular expressions).

So, you've added two taxonomies, let's assume their names are:

- product_type
- product_brand

We can use these in queries like so:

```
get_posts( array(
    'product_type' => 'cell-phones',
    'product_brand' => 'samsung'
) );
```

The query would be `?product_type=cell-phones&product_brand=samsung`. If you type that as your query you will get a list of Samsung phones. To rewrite `/cell-phones/samsung` into that query a rewrite rule must be added.

[`add_rewrite_rule()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) will do this for you. Here's an example of what your rewrite rule might look like for the above case:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?product_type=$matches[1]&product_brand=$matches[2]',
    'top' );
```

You will need to `flush_rewrite_rules()` as soon as you've added the rewrite rule to save it to the database. This is done only once, there is no need to do this with every request, once a rule is flushed its there. To remove it simply flush without the added rewrite rule.

If you want to add pagination you can do so by doing something like:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^products/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\d*)?',
    'index.php?product_type=$matches[1]&product_brand=$matches[2]&p=$matches[3]',
    'top' );
```

Comment: Single most simple article I've seen regarding wordpress rewrite rules. Been reading a lot but after reading this, finally got things working. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 4):

## The end result

**This is what I came up with partially using bits and pieces from all answers I've got:**

```
/**
 * Changes the permalink setting <:> post_type_link
 * Functions by looking for %product-type% and %product-brands% in the URL
 * 
  * products_type_link(): returns the converted url after inserting tags
  *
  * products_add_rewrite_rules(): creates the post type, taxonomies and applies the rewrites rules to the url
 *
 *
 * Setting:         [ produkter / %product-type%  / %product-brand% / %postname% ]
 * Is actually:     [ post-type / taxonomy        /  taxonomy       / postname   ]
 *                   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
 * Desired result:  [ products  / cellphones      / apple           / iphone-4   ]
 */

    // Add the actual filter    
    add_filter('post_type_link', 'products_type_link', 1, 3);

    function products_type_link($url, $post = null, $leavename = false)
    {
        // products only
        if ($post->post_type != 'products') {
            return $url;
        }

        // Post ID
        $post_id = $post->ID;

        /**
         * URL tag <:> %product-type%
         */
            $taxonomy = 'product-type';
            $taxonomy_tag = '%' . $taxonomy . '%';

            // Check if taxonomy exists in the url
            if (strpos($taxonomy_tag, $url) <= 0) {

                // Get the terms
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);

                if (is_array($terms) && sizeof($terms) > 0) {
                    $category = $terms[0];
                }

                // replace taxonomy tag with the term slug » /products/%product-type%/productname
                $url = str_replace($taxonomy_tag, $category->slug, $url);
            }

        /** 
         * URL tag <:> %product-brand%
         */
        $brand = 'product-brand';
        $brand_tag = '%' . $brand . '%';

        // Check if taxonomy exists in the url
        if (strpos($brand_tag, $url) < 0) {
            return $url;
        } else { $brand_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $brand); }

        if (is_array($brand_terms) && sizeof($brand_terms) > 0) {
            $brand_category = $brand_terms[0];
        }

        // replace brand tag with the term slug and return complete url » /products/%product-type%/%product-brand%/productname
        return str_replace($brand_tag, $brand_category->slug, $url);

    }

    function products_add_rewrite_rules() 
    {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        global $wp_query;

        /**
         * Post Type <:> products
         */

            // Product labels
            $product_labels = array (
                'name'                  => 'Products',
                'singular_name'         => 'product',
                'menu_name'             => 'Products',
                'add_new'               => 'Add product',
                'add_new_item'          => 'Add New product',
                'edit'                  => 'Edit',
                'edit_item'             => 'Edit product',
                'new_item'              => 'New product',
                'view'                  => 'View product',
                'view_item'             => 'View product',
                'search_items'          => 'Search Products',
                'not_found'             => 'No Products Found',
                'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No Products Found in Trash',
                'parent'                => 'Parent product'
            );

            // Register the post type
            register_post_type('products', array(
                'label'                 => 'Products',
                'labels'                => $product_labels,
                'description'           => '',
                'public'                => true,
                'show_ui'               => true,
                'show_in_menu'          => true,
                'capability_type'       => 'post',
                'hierarchical'          => true,
                'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'products'),
                'query_var'             => true,
                'has_archive'           => true,
                'menu_position'         => 5,
                'supports'              => array(
                                            'title',
                                            'editor',
                                            'excerpt',
                                            'trackbacks',
                                            'revisions',
                                            'thumbnail',
                                            'author'
                                        )
                )
            );

        /**
         * Taxonomy <:> product-type
         */
            register_taxonomy('product-type', 'products', array(
                'hierarchical' => true, 
                'label' => 'Product Types', 
                'show_ui' => true, 
                'query_var' => true, 
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products/types'),
                'singular_label' => 'Product Types') 
            );

        /**
         * Taxonomy <:> product-type
         */
            register_taxonomy('product-brand', 'products', array(
                'hierarchical' => true, 
                'label' => 'Product Brands', 
                'show_ui' => true, 
                'query_var' => true, 
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product/brands'),
                'singular_label' => 'Product Brands') 
            );

            $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['products'][0] = "/products/%product-type%/%product-brand%/%products%";

            // flush the rules
            flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    // rewrite at init
    add_action('init', 'products_add_rewrite_rules');
```

#### Some thoughts:

This does work. Although you're *'required'* to assign both taxonomies to each post or the URL will have a trailing `'/'` » `'/products/taxonomy//postname'`.
Since I'm going to assign both taxonomies to all my procuts, having a type and a brand, this code seems to be working for my needs. If anyone has any suggestions or improvesments feel free to reply!

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for posting your solution.  Please select it as the answer once enough time has past.  Also, it's recommended to up-vote any helpful answers.

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting this to work, not sure why. Even copying/pasting in to my functions rather than trying to port over your changes gives me tons of errors. I'm thinking something in WordPress's core must have changed between when this was written (over 3 years ago) and today. I'm trying to figure out the same thing: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180994/combining-multiple-taxonomies-in-one-url

Comment: `flush_rewrite_rules()` on `init`? don't to it. basically you are resetting your rewrite rules with each and every page load.

Answer (score 2):

While not your exact desired URL structure, you can get:

> **/products** 
>   » View all custom posts
>
> **/products/type/cell-phones** 
>   » View all custom posts with the taxonomy cell-phones
>
> **/products/type/cell-phones/brand/samsung** 
>   » View all custom posts where the taxonomy is cell-phones **AND** samsung
>
> **/brand/samsung** 
>   » View all custom posts where the taxonomy is samsung
>
> **/product/test-product-1** 
>   » View the product (single custom post)

without having to specify custom re-write rules.

It does require that you register your taxonomies and custom post types in a particular order though.  The trick is to register any taxonomy where the slug begins with your post-type's slug before you register that custom post type.  For example, assume the following slugs:

```
product_type taxonomy slug               = products/type
product custom_post_type slug            = product
product custom_post_type archive slug    = products
product_brand taxonomy slug              = brand
```

Then you could register them in this order:

```
register_taxonomy( 
    'products_type', 
    'products', 
        array( 
            'label' => 'Product Type', 
            'labels' => $product_type_labels,
            'public' => true, 
            'show_ui' => true, 
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true, 
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products/type', 'with_front' => false  ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'query_var' => true, 
        ) 
);

register_post_type('products', array(
    'labels' =>$products_labels,
    'singular_label' => __('Product'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product', 'with_front' => false ),
    'has_archive' => 'products',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions','comments','excerpt'),
 ));

register_taxonomy( 
    'products_brand', 
    'products', 
        array( 
            'label' => 'Brand', 
            'labels' => $products_brand_labels,
            'public' => true, 
            'show_ui' => true, 
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true, 
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'brand', 'with_front' => false  ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'query_var' => true, 
        ) 
);
```

If you absolutely have to have a URL like:

> **/products/type/cell-phones/brand/samsung/test-product-1** 
>   » View the product (single custom post)

Then you would require a rewrite rule something like this:

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '/products/type/*/brand/*/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename='product/$matches[1]',
        'top' );
```

**UPDATE** 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861291/multiple-custom-permalink-structures-in-wordpress

Here's how you correctly re-define the single post URL.

Set re-write to false for the custom post type.  (Leave the archive as is) and then after registering the taxonomies and posts, also register the following rewrite rules.

```
  'rewrite' => false

   global $wp_rewrite;
   $product_structure = '/%product_type%/%brand%/%product%';
   $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%product%", '([^/]+)', "product=");
   $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('product', $product_structure, false);
```

Then filter post_type_link to create the desired URL structure - allowing for unset taxonomy values.  Amending the code from the linked post, you'd have:

```
function product_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename){
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    if( 'product' != $post->post_type )
         return $permalink;

    $rewritecode = array(
    '%product_type%',
    '%brand%',
    $leavename? '' : '%postname%',
    $leavename? '' : '%pagename%',
    );

    if('' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))){

        if (strpos($permalink, '%product_type%') !== FALSE){

            $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product_type'); 

            if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))  
               $product_type = $terms[0]->slug;
            else 
               $product_type = 'unassigned-artist';         
        }

        if (strpos($permalink, '%brand%') !== FALSE){
           $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'brand');  
           if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) 
               $brand = $terms[0]->slug;
           else 
               $brand = 'unassigned-brand';         
        }           

        $rewritereplace = array(
           $product_type,
           $brand,
           $post->post_name,
           $post->post_name,
        );

        $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
    }
    return $permalink;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'product_permalink', 10, 3);
```

Now I just need to figure out how to re-write the brand taxonomy url without the leading brand tag, and I should match your desired URL exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Check this way, it still have some bugs with brand archive

http://pastebin.com/t8SxbDJy

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'products_type_link', 1, 3);

function products_type_link($url, $post = null, $leavename = false)
{
// products only
    if ($post->post_type != self::CUSTOM_TYPE_NAME) {
        return $url;
    }

    $post_id = $post->ID;

    $taxonomy = 'product_type';
    $taxonomy_tag = '%' . $taxonomy . '%';

    // Check if exists the product type tag
    if (strpos($taxonomy_tag, $url) < 0) {
        // replace taxonomy tag with the term slug: /products/%product_type%/samsumng/productname
        $url = str_replace($taxonomy_tag, '', $url);
    } else {
        // Get the terms
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);

        if (is_array($terms) && sizeof($terms) > 0) {
            $category = $terms[0];
            // replace taxonomy tag with the term slug: /products/%product_type%/samsumng/productname
            $url = str_replace($taxonomy_tag, $category->slug, $url);
        }
        }

    /* 
     * Brand tags 
     */
    $brand = 'product_brand';
    $brand_tag = '%' . $brand . '%';

    // Check if exists the brand tag 
    if (strpos($brand_tag, $url) < 0) {
        return str_replace($brand_tag, '', $url);
    }

    $brand_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, $brand);

    if (is_array($brand_terms) && sizeof($brand_terms) > 0) {
        $brand_category = $brand_terms[0];
    }

    // replace brand tag with the term slug: /products/cell-phone/%product_brand%/productname 
    return str_replace($brand_tag, $brand_category->slug, $url);
}

function products_add_rewrite_rules() 
{
global $wp_rewrite;
global $wp_query;

register_post_type('products', array(
    'label' => 'Products',
    'description' => 'GVS products and services.',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'menu_position' => 6,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'revisions',
        'thumbnail',
        'author'),
    'labels' => array (
        'name' => 'Products',
        'singular_name' => 'product',
        'menu_name' => 'Products',
        'add_new' => 'Add product',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New product',
        'edit' => 'Edit',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit product',
        'new_item' => 'New product',
        'view' => 'View product',
        'view_item' => 'View product',
        'search_items' => 'Search Products',
        'not_found' => 'No Products Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products Found in Trash',
        'parent' => 'Parent product'),
    ) 
);

register_taxonomy('product-categories', 'products', array(
    'hierarchical' => true, 
    'label' => 'Product Categories', 
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'query_var' => true, 
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
    'singular_label' => 'Product Category') 
);

$wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['products'][0] = "/products/%product_type%/%product_brand%/%products%";

    // product archive
    add_rewrite_rule("products/?$", 'index.php?post_type=products', 'top');

    /* 
     * Product brands
     */
    add_rewrite_rule("products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$", 'index.php?post_type=products&product_brand=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule("products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$", 'index.php?post_type=products&product_brand=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top');

    /*
     * Product type archive
     */
    add_rewrite_rule("products/([^/]+)/?$", 'index.php?post_type=products&product_type=$matches[1]', 'top');    
    add_rewrite_rule("products/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$", 'index.php?post_type=products&product_type=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[1]', 'bottom'); // product type pagination

    // single product
    add_rewrite_rule("products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$", 'index.php?post_type=products&product_type=$matches[1]&product_brand=$matches[2]&products=$matches[3]', 'top');



flush_rewrite_rules();
```

}

```
add_action('init', 'products_add_rewrite_rules');
```